# Second derivative of a function in a manifold along a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a function curve $\gamma(t)$ on a manifold $M$ . Define the function $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}\dot\gamma(t)^a\dot\gamma(t)^b$$

Introducing coordinates $x^i$ the first derivative of the function along the curve is
$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\dot\gamma(t)^i$$

I am confused in how we calculate the second derivative .

In this lecture [Lecture 10: Metric Manifolds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONCZNwKswn4&t=3494s&ab_channel=TheWE-HeraeusInternationalWinterSchoolonGravityandLight) to express the Euler-Lagrange equation it is calculated like this
$$\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\dot\gamma(t)^i\dot\gamma(t)^j +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\ddot\gamma(t)^i$$

but in this book [Relativity on Curved Manifolds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521429080) page 278,  in the taylor expansion of $f$ it is calculated like this
$$\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}\dot\gamma(t)^i\dot\gamma(t)^j +\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}a^i$$
where $a^{i}=\dot\gamma^{k} \nabla_{k} \gamma^{i}$ with $\nabla$ the covariante deivative

Which one is correct?

Comment: You will confuse us (and yourself) less if you write $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} (\gamma(t))$ and similarly for the second-order partials.

Comment: $\dot\gamma^i$ are the components of a vector field (dependent on the coordinate system, of course). These are not scalar functions defined independent of coordinates.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin components of a vector field are scalar function